# QDBus registerObject exposes non-existent objects

Tags: qtdbus

I'm working on exposing interfaces in Qt 5.3 on DBus.  I have an adapter that implements the org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager class modeled on the code at openSuse Imagewriter.

When I call registerObject with a path like "/com/company/blah/service" I see the proper interface.  The issue is that, not only do I see "/com/company/blah/service" in the object tree of d-feet, but I also see "/", "/com", "/com/company" and "/com/company/blah", each one of them exposing Introspectable, Peer and Properties, despite the fact these objects don't exist in my code.

When I create another adapter on my object and place it at "/com/company/blah/service2", it shows up as I would expect, as a new line in d-feet. Giving me:
    /
    /com              <- ?
    /com/company      <- ?
    /com/company/blah <- ?
    /com/company/blah/service
    /com/company/blah/service2

Doing some reading, I'm not seeing a restriction on object paths that requires this structure, nor am I seeing any option in registerObject or the qt library to prevent exposing these (fake) objects.

I used qdbusxml2cpp to generate my adapter class.  Code is running on a Debian 8 VM.

Is there some way to get these objects to not show up?